# Complex manifold and Hadamard theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry

The Hadamard theorem states that： any complete and simply connected manifold M with nonpositive sectional curvature is diffeomorphic to the euclidean space.

Is it also true if we assume that $M$ is a Hermitian manifold and replace sectional curvature with holomorphic sectional curvature？ If it’s not enough，how about changing nonpositive sectional curvature to semi-negative curvature form？

Thank you for your answer！

Comment: Named after Jacques Hadamard,  French mathematician.

Comment: @Narasimham thanks!

Comment: This is no answer, but an idea: holomorphic sectional curvature completly determines the curvature tensor (see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370955/about-an-explicit-formula-of-the-curvature-tensor-by-holomorphic-sectional-curva)). Hence, it determines the whole sectional curvature.

Comment: @Didier thanks! So although the holomorphic curvature tensor is negative-definite, sectional curvature(not holomorphic) is also possible to be positive by the formula,right?

Comment: @taiat To be fair, I don't know right now the answer to your question, and I don't really have time to do the full computations. Try to compute $R(X,Y,Y,X)$ with the linked formula and see what happens!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very much false. There used to be Yau's conjecture (dating to 1982-1983) about such manifolds, but it was disproven few years ago in

Jean-Paul Mohsen, [Construction of negatively curved complete intersections](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.10411.pdf).

In particular, there are compact simply connected Kahler manifolds of negative holomorphic sectional curvature (and even bisectional curvature). These manifolds are certain complete intersections in complex-projective spaces, the Kahler metric is the one induced from the ambient FS-metric. The difficulty is to ensure negative holomorphic curvature: The latter goes down for submanifolds but the ambient metric has positive holomorphic curvature.

Comment: I was so far away from knowing the answer, thinking I was just ignoring some classical result. What a beautiful example.